# jQuery Validation, displaying valid/invalid form tab(s) on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-validate

I have a form with Tabs, and a simple function to validate the form tabs as the user moves between them. (using jQuery, Bootstrap, and jquery.validate)

**Tab Validating Function**

```
var validateTab = function(element) {

    var _element = $(element);
    var validatePane = _element.attr('data-target');
    var isValid = $(validatePane + ' :input').valid();
    var _li = _element.parent();

    // console.log(validatePane + " - " + isValid);

    if (isValid) {
        _li.removeClass('alert-danger');
        _li.addClass('alert-success');
    } else {
        _li.removeClass('alert-success');
        _li.addClass('alert-danger');
    }
}; // end function validateTab
```

I'm currently listening to the bootstrap 'hidden.bs.tab' event and calling the function.

```
// Validate Tab on tab switch.
$(document).on('hidden.bs.tab', 'a[data-toggle="tab"]', function(e) {
    validateTab(e.currentTarget);
});
```

The above works as expected,  but I'd like to do this when the form is submitted also.  I added a simple loop to get each tab and call to validateTab() in invalidHandler() of jQuery validate

```
invalidHandler: function(event, validator) {
  console.log('invalid form');
  $('#myForm').append(
    '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">' +
    '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">' +
    '&times;' +
    '</button>' +
    '<strong>Error: </strong>' +
    '<span>Please correct the problems and try again.</span>' +
    '</div>'
  );

  // ADDED THIS CODE AND STARTED RUNNING INTO PROBLEMS.
  var $tabs = $('#myTab li a');
  $tabs.each(function(key, ele) {
    // IF last Tab of form is Valid form submits regardless of other errors.
    validateTab(ele);
  });

}
```

this works with one exception...  When the last tab is valid the form suddenly submits even if there are errors on the other tabs.  it appears calling valid overrides any previous calls or anything set prior to invalidHandler being called.  Suddenly the entire form submits as if it had been validated successfully.

a full example can be found here.
https://jsfiddle.net/qcean237/1/

Currently there is no validation on TAB 4 so submitting the form works every time even if none of the other required fields are provided.

Should I be validating the tabs a different way or in a different place to update the tab appearances on failed submits?

Thanks,
Nathan

Comment: exactly,  it all works until valid() is called on last tab.  When that last tab validates entire form is getting considered valid somehow.  calling valid() from inside invalidHandler() felt dirty, but its all I've come up with so far.

Comment: *"calling `valid()` from inside `invalidHandler()` felt dirty"* ~ and that's your root problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `invalidHandler` only fires when the form is invalid, and the `submitHandler` only fires when the form is valid.  That being said, your `validateTab()` function also triggers validation by calling `.valid()`.  In other words, you're breaking the plugin by causing the `invalidHandler` to check validity when `invalidHandler` already knows the form is invalid... this is the root of your failure.  The `invalidHandler` and `submitHandler` are only called *after* validity is determined... not concurrently, otherwise it can't know which handler should be fired.

Anyway, simply run `validateTab()` when you click the button...

```
$('button').on('click', function() {
    var $tabs = $('#myTab li a');
    $tabs.each(function(key, ele) {
        validateTab(ele);
    });
});
```

**DEMO:  [https://jsfiddle.net/qcean237/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/qcean237/2/)**

Comment: Thanks!  I got so wrapped up in solving this inside jquery.validate that completely missed this.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the code that validates each tab inside the invalidHandler. Since the tabs are already inside the form when you submit the form everything gets validated.

Simply remove the following lines from the `invalidHandler`

```
 $tabs.each(function(key, ele) {
   validateTab(ele);
 });
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sarojsasmal/wytanxxg/1/) after removing the above and everything works fine.

Comment: The OP specifically stated, *"but I'd like to do this when the form is submitted also"*

Comment: Your answer makes sense to me.. Nice explanation. Thanks!!